# How do I dismiss a keyboard after my user has entered the value for a text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question has been asked a few times, but none of the answers have enough detail for me (me = n00b) to understand.

I have a simple little app that I put together via the storyboard, it has two text fields that the user can type into. I want the user to be able to dismiss the keyboard after they edit either field.

I know it has something to do with "resignFirstResponder" but I'm not sure where to put that.

Here is my top secret code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize thing1;
@synthesize thing2;

// NSArray things = @[thing1, thing2];
// self.thingLabel.text = array[arc4random()%array.count];
- (IBAction)pick:(id)sender {
    // create an empty list that will get filled with things
    NSMutableArray *things = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:thing1.text,thing2.text, nil];
    NSString *theThing = things[arc4random()%things.count];
    NSLog(@"the thing is %@", theThing);
}

@end
```

and here is my ViewController.h file:

```
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *thing1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *thing2;


@end
```

Comment: where is your UITextField delegate methods implementation??? Are you conform text field delegate protocol in .h file yeah link it into nib file?

Comment: sorry.. I can't add code to a comment.. one second

Comment: nah!!!! its your ViewController.m implementation file, check it properly.

Comment: @Reformer ...sorry, I'm new to this stuff. I added the .h file as well above

Comment: It ok. I'm interested first whether you set delegate or not for UITextField. Hmm so that means you connect UItextFielddelegate in nib right?

Comment: @Reformer that's kinda over my head but I'm sure that I didn't do anything extra on the storyboard

Comment: You must go through this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingTextClasses/UsingTextClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your view controller adopts the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol (i.e., `<UITextFieldDelegate>`), then the easiest technique is to have the view controller implement the following two methods:

```
// place in ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // note that you could set the text field delegate in IB instead
    self.thing1.delegate = self;
    self.thing2.delegate = self;
}

// this method gets called by the system automatically when the user taps the keyboard's "Done" button
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

That's all the code you need. Now when the user taps the keyboard's "Done" button, the keyboard goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a button beside the textfield and dismiss it when that one is pressed:

```
UIButton *doneEnteringButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[doneEnteringButton addTarget:addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

This single button will dismiss the keyboard, no matter which textfield you are in. If you don't want the button a cool way would be to add a gesture recognizer to the parent view of the textfield and do `endEditing:YES` there.

Hope this helps! Ask if it doesn't

Comment: sounds ok.. but I don't want any clutter. Sorry, stubborn designer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, when user tap any where to dismiss keyboard

```
- (void)setupKeyboardDismiss{
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGR =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(tapAnywhereToDismissKeyboard:)];
    NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [nc addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                    object:nil
                     queue:mainQueue
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
                    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGR];
                }];
    [nc addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                    object:nil
                     queue:mainQueue
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
                    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:singleTapGR];
                }];
}

- (void)tapAnywhereToDismissKeyboard:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok,the controller is your controller, change controller.view to self.view.

Comment: Thanks, that makes xcode not angry anymore but the keyboard still doesn't get dismissed.

Comment: Change 
interface ViewController : UIViewController
to
interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: So, I did that and it still doesn't work. I feel like this is harder that it should be (for me).  In ViewController.h I now have this: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: Do you use nib or storyboard? if you use nib, you must to link the textField on you nib.

Comment: I wonder if there is something simple that I'm just leaving out... I really want your code to work. Thanks for trying!!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the UI & functionality you are trying to develop. You can do it in following ways:

1. Add a "Done" button to your UI for user to take an action once they are done with entering data in text fields and then in the action handler for that button call `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]`.
2. Add a custom keyboard down button to your keyboard.
3. Implement the below delegate methods on `UITextField` and put logic in them and call   `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]` once the required criterion is met. For example once user has entered certain number of characters it will auto-dismiss the keyboard.
4. When user is done and tap outside the textfield view, dismiss the keyboard. Implement 'touchesbegan' on UIView and let the viewcontroller about it.

   ```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)iTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementString:(NSString *)iString 

   -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)iTextField
   ```

Comment: Is it reasonable to want "4. when the user taps outside of the text field"?

Comment: Yes. Thats also makes sense. You can implement `touchesbegan` for that.